# How to declare and assign value for a class that has array variable?

Tags: c#

how to assign value for an array variable when it is declared in different class? Below is the sample codes for easier understanding of my problem:-

```
// Below is a class customer that has three parameters: 
// One string parameter and Two int array parameter

public class Customer
{
    public string invoiceFormat { get; set; }
    public int [] invoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public int [] customerPointer { get; set; }

    public Customer(
        string invoiceFormat, 
        int[] invoiceNumber, 
        int[] customerPointer) 
    {
        this.invoiceFormat = invoiceFormat;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.customerPointer = customerPointer;
    }
}

// How to assign value for invoiceNumber or customerPointer array in 
// different windows form?
// The following codes is executed in windowsform 1

public static int iValue=0;
public static Customer []c = new Customer [9999];

c[iValue] = new Customer(textBox16.Text, invoiceNumber[0].iValue + 1, 
                         customerPointer[0].iValue);

// I have an error that the name 'invoiceNumber and customerPointer' 
// does not exist inthe current context
```

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish: "invoiceNumber[0].iValue + 1"?

Comment: when passing in your arrays you are passing in an element of the array and not the array itself. invoiceNumber[0] indicates the first element of the array.  invoiceNumber is the array

Comment: System Down: This is billing system. Class customer stores an array number of invoice numbers. So, in my windows form, when i load billing form. The billing form access into customer class and stores new invoicenumber to the array. So i need to know the codes how to pass the value array invoiceNumber.

Comment: @Sorceri This is my situation. This is a billing system, on my billing form, when i add new invoice. I have to store the invoice number to the existing customer with invoice number updated. Instead of array if i declare normal int type. There is no error and its working perfect. But, my condition is that, the customer must have array number of invoices. Please, can you give me sample codes how to solve my problem. Thank you –

//If i declare this way, there is no error . And my customer class has no array... Is normal int type
c[iValue] = new Customer(textBox16.Text, iValue + 1, iValue);

Answer (score 1):

what you have

```
c[iValue] = new Customer(textBox16.Text, invoiceNumber[0].iValue + 1, customerPointer[0].iValue);
```

which is completely wrong and is why you get the error :  the name 'invoiceNumber and customerPointer' does not exist inthe current context

you never declare any array for invoiceNumber or CustomerPointers.  Both of these are members of your class which is where I think you are getting confused.  I am not even going to take a guess at what invoiceNumber[0].iValue +1 is to be as an int has no members, its a data type

so to fix this we would do something such as

```
        //create some arrays
        int[] invoicesNums = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] customerPtrs = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        //create a new customer
        Customer customer = new Customer("some invoice format", invoicesNums, customerPtrs);

        //add the customer to the first element in the static array
        Form1.c[0] = customer;
```

ok so thats how you should do that however, I really think you need to stop and take a deeper look into classes, arrays, data types and OOP as this will save you from a major headache when you get further down the road with your Program.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a value that does not exist yet.  Look at your constructor:

```
public Customer(string invoiceFormat, int[] invoiceNumber, int[] customerPointer) 
{
            this.invoiceFormat = invoiceFormat;
            this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
            this.customerPointer = customerPointer;
 }
```

This means you need to pass a string, a FULL array of  `int` and another COMPLETE array of `int`.  By attempting to do this:

```
c[iValue] = new Customer(textBox16.Text, invoiceNumber[0].iValue + 1, customerPointer[0].iValue);
```

You are calling upon variables that don't exist yet.  Think about the word constructor.  That creates the object and initializes the internal variables.  `invoiceNumber[]` and `customerPointer[]` are never assigned by passing another array parameter.  This is why you are receiving that error message.  If you used your constructor to initialize those arrays and then pass a single `invoiceNumber` and single `customerPointer`, which are then added to the initialized array then this would work.  However, it sounds like your internal values should not be arrays, then you'd be able to just pass a single `int` value for each of those parameters.

Comment: This is my situation. This is a billing system, on my billing form, when i add new invoice. I have to store the invoice number to the existing customer with invoice number updated. Instead of array if i declare normal int type. There is no error and its working perfect. But, my condition is that, the customer must have array number of invoices. Please, can you give me sample codes how to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: It appears you need to learn about how to use classes properly.  You need to add methods to add additional invoices numbers and "customerpointer" values.  You keep constructing new customers instead of modifying an existing customer.

Comment: Can you tell me how to assign value for the following invoiceNumber parameter in different windows form.

public class Invoice(){
        
            public int [] invoiceNumber { get; set; }

            public Invoice (int [] invoice )
            {
                this.invoiceNumber=invoice;
            }
        }

Comment: SO is NOT for asking for code without demonstrating a basic understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.  I am more than happy to help out with questions on why you are receiving errors, but you need a tutorial on how to use classes or do object oriented programming.

Comment: I know to write the code when the parameter is not an array.
Eg: Invoice [] in= new Invoice[10]; 
in[0]= new Invoice(10);

Comment: Pass an array in the constructor or build methods to add individual invoices once at a time.